# Limiting forms for modified Bessel functions of the 2nd kind when $x \to 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, bessel-functions

**Case 1**

Consider the behaviour of [the modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) for $x \to 0$, when $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n = 0$. Abramowitz and Stegun (Handbook of Mathematical Functions, par. 9.6.8), state that

$$K_0 (x) \propto - \log(x)$$

where $\log$ is the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm). But [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BesselK%5B0%2Cx%5D%20series%20at%20x%20-%3E%200) gives a more complete expression:

$$K_0 (x) \simeq - \log (x) - \gamma + \log (2) \ldots$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) constant. This is called a *generalized Puiseux series*.

**Case 2**

For $x \to 0$, the ratio

$$\frac{K_0 (x)}{x K_1 (x)}$$

has the same 0-th order term $- \log (x) - \gamma + \log (2)$, as $K_0 (x)$ alone, in its *generalized Puiseux series* [expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BesselK%5B0%2Cx%5D%2F%28x*BesselK%5B1%2Cx%5D%29%20series%20at%20x%20-%3E%200).

**My question:**

How is the number $\gamma$ generated? And how to compute this 0-th order term in both cases?

Comment: One can start with obtaining the series representation for [$J_\nu(z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1), then the leading terms in the expansion of [$K_0(z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) are given by
$$\frac 1 2 \lim_{\nu \to 0} \left(
 \Gamma(\nu) \left( \frac z 2 \right)^{-\nu} +
  \Gamma(-\nu) \left( \frac z 2 \right)^\nu \right).$$

Comment: @Maxim Sorry, why $\displaystyle \lim_{\nu \to 0}$? Shouldn't it be $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0}$?